# Simular evento click JavaScript para laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel-5, laravel-blade

tengo un formulario de captura, mi problema es que cuando quiero ver o editar algunas opciones las tengo ocultas si el usuario da click en el radio se activa otros radios o campos de texto esto me funciona a la perfección.

Mi duda es ¿como simulo el evento click al llenar mi formulario? ya que al llenarlo los radios que muestran contenido oculto se llenan pero no me muestran el contenido oculto, solo si doy clic manual se muestra.

este es mi div con los radios y mi función JS

```
      <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                    4.- ¿Utiliza medidas de protección auditiva?
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm">
                <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
                  {{ Form::radio('aud_preg_4', 'S', ($cuestionario->aud_preg_4 == 'S'), array('id'=>'preg_4_s','class' => 'custom-control-input','required'=>'required')) }}
                  <label class="custom-control-label" for="preg_4_s">
                        Siempre
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
                    {{ Form::radio('aud_preg_4', 'A', ($cuestionario->aud_preg_4 == 'A'), array('id'=>'preg_4_a','class' => 'custom-control-input','required'=>'required')) }}
                    <label class="custom-control-label" for="preg_4_a">
                        A veces
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
                    {{ Form::radio('aud_preg_4', 'N', ($cuestionario->aud_preg_4 == 'N'), array('id'=>'preg_4_n','class' => 'custom-control-input','required'=>'required')) }}
                    <label class="custom-control-label" for="preg_4_n">
                        Nunca
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> <!--  Pregunta 4 -->

        <div class="form-group row d-none" id="preg_4_1">
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                    4.1.- ¿Qué tipo de equipo de protección utiliza?
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm">
                <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
                  {{ Form::radio('aud_preg_4_1', 'T', ($cuestionario->aud_preg_4_1 == 'T'), array('id'=>'preg_4_1_t','class' => 'custom-control-input')) }}
                  <label class="custom-control-label" for="preg_4_1_t">
                        Tapones
                    </label>
                </div>
                  <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
                    {{ Form::radio('aud_preg_4_1', 'O', ($cuestionario->aud_preg_4_1 == 'O'), array('id'=>'preg_4_1_o','class' => 'custom-control-input')) }}
                    <label class="custom-control-label" for="preg_4_1_o">
                        Orejeras
                    </label>
                  </div>
            </div>
        </div> <!--  Pregunta 4.1 -->




$('#preg_4_a').click(function() {
    if($(this).is(':checked')) { 
        $('#preg_4_1').removeClass('d-none');
        $('#preg_4_1').attr("required","required");
    }
});   

$('#preg_4_s').click(function() {
    if($(this).is(':checked')) { 
        $('#preg_4_1').removeClass('d-none');
        $('#preg_4_1_t').attr("required","required");
        $('#preg_4_1_o').attr("required","required");
    }
});

 $('#preg_4_n').click(function() {
    if($(this).is(':checked')) { 
        $('#preg_4_1').addClass('d-none');
        $('#preg_4_1_t').removeAttr("required");
        $('#preg_4_1_o').removeAttr("required");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza la función `trigger` de `JQuery` ([Aqui](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) puedes la documentación):

```
$('#nombreDeTuBoton').trigger('click');
```

O utiliza la función click(); de `javascript`:

```
document.getElementById('nombreDeTuBoton').click();
```

Comment: Gracias ya quedo